# Prevent Text in Jetpack Compose from enlarging when device font size is increases

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen in my app which displays a timer. If the user decides to increase the font size in the device settings menu then the text becomes too large for the layout and it begins to wrap. This is not an issue for my other screens that are more text heavy. For this screen - and only this screen - I would prefer to prevent the timer text from increasing in size if accessibility options are used.

[image: Well formatted compose page]
[image: Device font settings]
[image: Poorly formatted compose page]

The code in question looks like this, if it adds context:

```kotlin
HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, dragEnabled = dragEnabled) { page ->
    val timeInSeconds = abs(steps[page % steps.size] / 1000L)
    val minutes = (timeInSeconds / 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')
    val seconds = (timeInSeconds % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.85f),
        text = stringResource(R.string.pomodoro_active_notification_content_body, minutes, seconds),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = LocalDimens.current.intervalTimeFontSize,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
    )
}
```

Comment: You would need to specify a font size in `dp` instead of `sp`, and I am sure that `MaterialTheme` uses `sp`.

Comment: If this is the only screen you want this code change to be applied to, why not just declare a top-level `val` and hard-code the size for the screen? Just use AS to replace all the instances of the old reference with the new val and you're good, I assume.

Comment: @CommonsWare the composable `Text` does not accept `dp`, only `TextUnit` which is either a `sp` or `em`.

Comment: Yeah, I think you have to do some conversions to undo the text scale. Suppose you want `16dp` and the user has a 1.5x text scale. If you try using `16.sp`, you get `24dp` in actual size. You can get the current text scale (`LocalConfiguration` IIRC). So, you would compute the "anti-scaled" size = 16 / 1.5 = 10.66 and apply `.sp` to it, so when the text scale gets applied, you get your desired `16dp` size.

Comment: Btw., your date formatting seems pretty verbose. You might use official APIs for that, e.g. java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As @CommonsWare correctly pointed out, you need to reverse scaling.

You can get `fontScale` from `LocalDensity`:

```
val Int.nonScaledSp
    @Composable
    get() = (this / LocalDensity.current.fontScale).sp
```

Usage:

```
10.nonScaledSp
```

---

An other option is using `dp` related text size: it's gonna ignore system **Font Size** setting, but it's gonna take **Display size** setting into account - it can be useful in cases when you have some container view size in `dp` and wanna text to have size related to the parent parent:

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
val textSize = with(density) { 15.dp.toSp() }
```

Comment: Thanks! But it would be so easy if they just left availability to set dp for font size

Comment: I cannot reach for LocalDimens , has it been replaced ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén is just a constant used by the author of the question, I replaced it so there would be no misunderstanding

Comment: how can i just apply this for whole application

Answer (score 10):

Its pretty easy actually. You can just set new `CompositionLocalProvider` like this

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalDensity provides Density(
        LocalDensity.current.density,
        1f // - we set here default font scale instead of system one
    )
) {
    //your composables that will use no-scale
}
```

And please remember that text scaling exists for a purpose. Don't just wrap you whole application in this composition local. **Accessibility is really important**

You can check max scale for your element to work correctly and than write something like:

```
val myFontScale = LocalDensity.current.fontScale.coerceIn(0.75f, 1.5f)
```

And then simply pass this value `CompositionLocal` instead of `1f`

Answer (score 3):

This is an extension function for Int but you can do it for Float if you wish to

```
@Composable
fun Int.scaledSp(): TextUnit {
    val value: Int = this
    return with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val fontScale = this.fontScale
        val textSize =  value / fontScale
        textSize.sp
  }
```

Comment: This working as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We can use [CompositionLocalProvider](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) to override the default font scale:

```
@Composable
fun TextWithFixedSize(
    text: String,
    fontSize: TextUnit,
) {
    val newDensity = Density(
        LocalDensity.current.density,
        fontScale = 2f,
    )
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalDensity provides newDensity,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            fontSize = fontSize,
        )
    }
}
```

If you want to use a fixed text size on all the pages of your app, just wrap your root composable with the CompositionLocalProvider.

The same app with different font size settings:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

```
val textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.h1

val fontSizeDp = with(LocalDensity.current) { textStyle.fontSize.value.dp.toSp() }
Text(
    ...
    style = textStyle,
    fontSize = fontSizeDp,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextUnitType.Unspecified` to ignore system scale:

```
Text(
    text = "text",
    color = Color.White,
    fontSize = TextUnit(18f, TextUnitType.Unspecified),
)
```