# Using text as a fixed font size in android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `Text` in Compose, and I want to treat the font size as a fixed value regardless of the system setting. However, the font-size of text allows only `sp`. Therefore, it is difficult to apply a fixed font value. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108033/prevent-text-in-jetpack-compose-from-enlarging-when-device-font-size-is-increase