How to keep the button size the same despite the accessibility scaling?
In Jetpack compose I have a button:
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(350.dp)
                .height(50.dp),
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Text(text = "MY TEXT")
        }

The problem is that once a user uses accessibility and increases the "display size"

my button (as expected) increases accordingly, what I am trying to find out is - is there a way to keep the button size the same despite the accessibility scale?
UPD
I just wanted to point out that my question is about the button size, not the text size.
UPD2
The possible solution probably could be
val Int.nonScale: Dp
    @Composable get() {
        val density: Float = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.density
        return (this / density).dp
    }

usage:

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(1000.nonScale)
...


refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108033/prevent-text-in-jetpack-compose-from-enlarging-when-device-font-size-is-increase

Is your concern the size of the button or the size of the text? The above comment is for the size of the text.

@sasikumar updated my question with UPD section, my question is mostly about the button size, not the text.

@CommonsWare updated my question with UPD section, my question is mostly about the button size, not the text. Is there any suggestions?

You could look into the techniques outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/q/56779224/115145. While the question itself is about a React Native app, the answers are all for native Android. That said, make sure that you are doing the right thing for your users; ignoring their request to make the UI elements bigger may not be the right thing.

@CommonsWare yep, that answer describes an activity solution, but I was looking for something related to the specific view, kind of extension like width = 48.dp.nonScaled

In theory, I think you can adapt those "create a replacement Configuration" approaches to update LocalConfiguration.current for the desired scope (e.g., a specific composable).

@CommonsWare I've added a possible solution in the UPD2 section in my question. But there I am relying on px instead of dp. Can you think about a possible disadvantage of this approach? I mean if it is necessary to make a button non-scalable and look the same despite the scaling factor.

That wipes out all density calculations, not just the dynamic density that occurs with the display scaling. If it gives you the desired results across a range of actual physical densities, it should be OK, especially for a large item where making it bigger is unnecessary.

with(LocalDensity.current) { 120.toDp() }

With the code above you can use same pixel size for all dpi levels. But in this approach, you gotta find the perfect one pixel sizing for all dpi levels.
For a second approach:
val pixels = LocalContext.current.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pixels)
val size = with(LocalDensity.current) { pixels.toDp() }

you can create pixel values for every dpi level, then you can retrieve and use it with the code above.

Although its not a recommended approach and user expect to scale the text or size depending on the settings but even then if you wwant to achieve this the I guess you can use size instead of height and width something like this :
 modifier = Modifier.size(350.dp, 50.dp)

*NOTE - I haven't tried on my own

nope it works the same way
